# Add a site language using powershell Pnponline or SPOService

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-online

I create users via a ps command like this

```
New-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName $user.Email -Password $user.Password [...] -PreferredLanguage fr-FR
```

Knowing that the tenant is in German (de-DE) all the web apps are in german (See image)

[image: Apps German]

So i need to connect to the sharepoint site to be able to add french like this

[image: FR-SP]

But I need to do it with powershell because I make a lot of accounts daily with the script.

So I followed a ["how to do"](https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2019/03/sharepoint-online-enable-document-id-service-using-powershell.html) where it is given the ps commands like this:

```
> Install-Module -Name Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.PowerShell -SkipPublisherCheck -Force
> $user = "Testuser@my_tenant.onmicrosoft.com"
> $password = ConvertTo-SecureString 'a_secret_password_here' -AsPlainText -Force
> $creds = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($user,$password)
> Connect-PnPOnline -Url "https://my_tenant-my.sharepoint.com/personal/Testuser_my_tenant_onmicrosoft_com/_layouts/15/muisetng.aspx" -Credentials $creds
> $Web = Get-PnPWeb
> $Web.AddSupportedUILanguage(1036) (French)
> $web.Update()
> Invoke-PnPQuery
```

but the problem is that this only works if the user has logged in once manually on the sharepoint site, where all of a sudden it kind of creates the user sharepoint url "
"https://my_tenant-my.sharepoint.com/personal/Testuser_my_tenant_onmicrosoft_com/_layouts/15/muisetng.aspx"

If it was done before (Just logging in and not thicking the FR button), the script thicks the button like here:

[image: FR-Thicked]

Otherwise i get the 404 not found error like this

[image: Error 404]

Any Ideas how to do it without having to log in?

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I got in touch with the Microsoft Support and they told me that the Onedrive site, which causes the Error 404, is not created until the user logs in to onedrive admin site. And so one must first pre provision the personal account like shown on the microsoft [documentations](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/pre-provision-accounts) website Onedrive, the code looks like this:

```
> $user = "userXX@tenant.onmicrosoft.com"
> $password = ConvertTo-SecureString 'my_personal_password' -AsPlainText -Force
> $creds = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($user,$password)
> Connect-MsolService -Credential $creds
> Connect-SPOService -Url "https://[userXX]-admin.sharepoint.com" -Credential $creds
> Request-SPOPersonalSite -UserEmails "[userXX]@[tenant].onmicrosoft.com"
> # The provisioning takes some time, so if one connects directly after creation, 
> #then the 404 error happens again, so we put a pause to the script
> Start-sleep -seconds 30
> Connect-PnPOnline -Url "https://tenant-my.sharepoint.com/personal/[userXX]_[tenant]_onmicrosoft_com/_layouts/15/muisetng.aspx" -Credentials $creds
> $Web = Get-PnPWeb
> $web.IsMultilingual = $true
> $Web.AddSupportedUILanguage(1036) #(French)
> $web.Update()
> Invoke-PnPQuery
```

So, the variables are `[UserXX]` and `[tenant]` which are basically the created user and the company's (or personal) name